# paramiko hangs at _get_channel while using multiprocessing

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, python-multiprocessing

I have the following code (written using paramiko) which gets called in multiprocessing process

```
       def traffic(q, e):
            e.open()

       def open()
            assert self.closed
            self._channel = self._get_channel()
            self.stdin      = io.TextIOWrapper(CommandStdIn(self._channel))
            self.stdout = self._channel.makefile()
            self.stderr = self._channel.makefile_stderr()

       q = Queue()
       p = Process(target = self.traffic, args = (q, other_args))
       p.start()
       p.join()
```

Without multiprocessing, this works just fine. But with multiprocessing, it stops at

```
 %paramiko.transport-WARNING: Success for unrequested channel! [??]
 %paramiko.transport-ERROR: Channel request for unknown channel 19
```

It hangs at the `self._get__channel()` part. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

When the connection is established within another process, what happens is that the child process gets a copy of the socket associated with the channel. What happens is we get two objects trying to communicate with single socket and the session gets corrupted. Explained here 
[Paramiko Sessions Closes Transport in the Child Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33671328/paramiko-sessions-closes-transport-in-the-child-process)
and here 
https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/446